# Cypress get element in XML file?

Tags: xml, cypress

How do I write a Cypress test that reads an XML file and checks that an element matches a specified value?

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Establishment>
        <Detail>
            <BusinessName>Pizza</BusinessName>
        </Detail>
</Establishment>
```

I am trying to get the `BusinessName` element and check that it matches a string.

Answer (score 4):

When you read an XML file with `cy.readFile()` or receive XML in an API response, it is  a string (text). You would need to parse it to an XML document to test efficiently.

[DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) is the browser object to do the parsing.

```js
cy.readFile('path-to-my-xml-file')
  .then(xmlText => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlText, "application/xml");
    const businessNameContent = doc.querySelector('BusinessName').textContent
    expect(businessNameContent).to.eq('Pizza')
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also install package [x2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x2js) to change the XML to JSON, then use `.` property to test deeply nested properties, for example

```js
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/test.xml')
  .then(xml => {
    const X2JS = require('x2js')
    const x2js = new X2JS()
    const json = x2js.xml2js(xml)

    expect(json.Establishment.Detail.BusinessName).to.eq('Pizza')
  })
```